# generate matrix with np.zeros Python - Matrix must be 2 dimensinonal error

Tags: python, matrix

Hey I want to generate a zero matrix. Therefore my idea is using 3 zerovectors. Unfortunately I get the error:

"matrix must be 2-dimensional"

here is my code:

```
dx=0.5
dy=0.5
dz=0.5
npoints = 9         #count of total x-values
x=np.arange(-2.,2.1,dx)
y=np.arange(-2.,2.1,dy)
z=np.arange(-2.,2.1,dz)
M=np.matrix(([x,y,z]))
print M
print 
print
Vx= np.zeros((1, npoints))
print Vx
Vy=np.zeros((1,npoints))
Vz=np.zeros((1,npoints))
V=np.matrix(([Vx,Vy]))
```

I get the error at the second matrix. What is my mistake ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a matrix from a three-dimensional array, because `Vx` and `Vy` are already two-dimensional by the way you created them (although one axis has length 1). There are several possible remedies such as creating `Vx` et al. one-dimensional:

```
Vx=np.zeros(npoints)
```

or creating your matrix directly

```
V=np.matrix(np.zeros(2,npoints))
```

And probably many others.

Note that your error in understanding may be that `np.zeros` takes a shape as input not some kind of coordinate range. So you can just create an array of whatever shape you want directly with `np.zeros`. The above call for example generates a 2x`npoints` matrix.